# How much TP does each Order Rating require?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Whenever you complete an order in battle you are given a rating of Cool, Bravo, or Amazing based on how much TP you earned. These ratings determine how many party members are reactivated. How much TP is needed for each of these order ratings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my own testing and an article by [Goomba Stomp](https://goombastomp.com/xenoblade-chronicles-3-chain-attacks/).

- 100%-149% TP: Cool (1 reactivation)
- 150%-199% TP: Bravo (2 reactivations)
- 200% or more TP: Amazing (3 reactivations)