# Do Tactical Points matter for the last turn of a chain attack?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

At the end of a Chain Attack turn the number of Tactical Points you earn determines [how many party members are reactivated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/399188/181240). However, reactivated party members don't matter if it's the last turn of a Chain Attack or you're about to reactivate the entire party with an Ouroboros Order.

Do Tactical Points have any use during the last turn of a chain attack when you can't reactivate party members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of. The threshold (Good, Bravo, Amazing) affects the damage multiplier bonus that you get at the end of the turn. So, reaching 200TP helps to maximize the damage output of the final order, but going above that isn't necessary.

[The Xeno Series Wiki](https://www.xenoserieswiki.org/wiki/Chain_Attack_(XC3)#Damage_multiplier) explains the calculations behind the damage multiplier.

> [The] base [damage] increase also receives a boost depending on the round's result. It doesn't increase as rounds go on, but it has a higher cap for "Amazing" rounds. Furthermore, it doesn't depend on the exact number of TP gained during the round, but rather on meeting three thresholds.
>
> | Result | Normal gain | Key pair gain | Max gain |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Cool (100 TP) | 0 | 0 | 0 |
> | Bravo (150 TP) | random(25, 50) | random(35, 70) | 50 |
> | Amazing (200 TP) | random(75, 150) | random(100, 200) | 150 |